# How do I make groupinstall work on XenServer 6.2?

Tags: centos, yum, xenserver

I have a XenServer system that I'm wanting to add some extra packages to.

The problem I have is that XenServer is based on a stripped down CentOS 5.6 installation and the command "yum grouplist" returns no group data.

Ultimately, what I'm wanting to do is to be able to run this commands successfully.

```
yum groupinstall "Infiniband Support"
```

Answer (score 0):

If XenServer's repositories don't support groups, you'll have to mirror the RPMs locally and merge your own group file into the metadata. *Theoretically*.

You could copy CentOS 6.2's group file.. or 5.6... I'm not sure which would be correct in this case. Either  way, the filename ends in "`comps.xml`" and is found in the repodata directory on the installation media. You can re-create the repodata with the group data with the following command;

`createrepo -g /path/to/mirror/repodata/3a2723269...-c6-x86_64-comps.xml -pd /path/to/mirror`

It goes without saying that what you are doing is unsupported. You might break things or it might not work at all. This is how groups work with Yum, though. Good luck.